# Time-bandwidth product (width of Gaussian) using numpy.fft

Tags: python, numpy, math, physics

I would like to Fourier Transform simulated laser pulses from the time-domain to the frequency domain using Python. I am starting with a Gaussian function, since it is known that the "time-bandwidth product" (the width in the time domain multiplied by the width in the frequency domain) is [0.44](https://www.rp-photonics.com/gaussian_pulses.html), when the width is defined in terms of terms of the full-width-at-half-maximum of the Gaussian.

However, when using `numpy.fft.fft`, I find that the time-bandwidth product is 0.88, two times what it should be.

[image]
Here is my code (minimal example in the first few lines, the rest is just making plots):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fwhm = 40e-15 # using a 40 femtosecond pulse

t  = np.linspace(-500e-15, 500e-15, 2000)
Et = np.exp( -t**2 / (2*(fwhm / 2.35482)**2) ) # gaussian function

Ef = np.abs(np.fft.fftshift( np.fft.fft(Et) )) # take the fourier transform
f  = np.fft.fftshift( np.fft.fftfreq(Ef.shape[0],t[1]-t[0]) ) # generate the frequencies

fwhm_fft = 2 * np.abs( f[ np.argmin(np.abs(0.5*np.max(Ef)-Ef)) ] ) # find the fwhm of the frequnecy-domain signal

print 'Observed time-bandwidth product: %.3f'%(fwhm*fwhm_fft)

# just making plots from here onwards:
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,1, figsize=(6,8))

axs[0].set_title('Time domain')
axs[0].plot(t,Et)
axs[0].axvline(-fwhm*0.5, color='r', alpha=0.5, label='Full-width at half-maximum (FWHM) = %.1f fs'%(fwhm*1e15))
axs[0].axvline( fwhm*0.5, color='r', alpha=0.5)

axs[0].set_ylim(0,1.3)
axs[0].set_xlabel('Time (sec)')

axs[1].set_title('Frequency domain')
axs[1].plot(f,Ef)

axs[1].axvline(-0.44/fwhm*0.5, color='r', alpha=0.5, label='FWHM should be %.1f THz'%(0.44/fwhm*1e-12) )
axs[1].axvline( 0.44/fwhm*0.5, color='r', alpha=0.5)

axs[1].axvline(-fwhm_fft*0.5, color='g', alpha=0.5, label='FWHM is actually %.1f THz'%(fwhm_fft*1e-12) )
axs[1].axvline( fwhm_fft*0.5, color='g', alpha=0.5)

axs[1].set_xlim(-5e13,5e13)
axs[1].set_ylim(0,120)
axs[1].set_xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')

for ax in axs:
    ax.legend(fontsize=10)
    ax.set_ylabel('Electric field intensity (arbitrary units)')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('time-bandwidth-product.png', dpi=200)
plt.show()
```

Comment: your Gaussian is unnormalized, leading to a different fwhm then you intended, check [Gaussian](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianFunction.html). the normallizing prefactor is 1/(sigma*sqrt(2*pi))

Comment: You are correct, it is not normalized. But the height of the Gaussian should not affect the width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@PaulPanzer was on the right track! When comparing the FWHM of two Gaussian functions, we do indeed expect to find 0.88 as the time-bandwidth product.

But why do most references  [[1](http://www.cmxr.com/Education/TBproduct.html),[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth-limited_pulse),[3]](https://www.rp-photonics.com/time_bandwidth_product.html) say that 0.44 is the time-bandwidth product for a laser pulse? The key is that what we actually observe is the intensity (I) of the electric field (E), where I=E^2. So, practically, it makes the most sense to compare the width of the *intensity* profiles, not the *electric field* profiles. When we compare the intensity profiles, we find that the time-bandwidth product is indeed 0.44.

Revised code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fwhm = 40e-15 # using a 40 femtosecond pulse

t  = np.linspace(-1000e-15, 1000e-15, 4000)
It = np.exp( -t**2 / (2*(fwhm / 2.35482)**2) ) # Intensity in the time domain
Et = np.sqrt(It)                               # E-field in the time domain

Ef = np.abs(np.fft.fftshift( np.fft.fft(Et) )) # FT to get E-field in frequency domain
If = Ef**2                                     # Intensity in the frequnecy domain
f  = np.fft.fftshift( np.fft.fftfreq(Ef.shape[0],t[1]-t[0]) ) # generate the frequencies

fwhm_fft = 2 * np.abs( f[ np.argmin(np.abs(0.5*np.max(If)-If)) ] ) # find the fwhm of the frequency-domain signal

print 'Observed time-bandwidth product: %.3f'%(fwhm*fwhm_fft)


# just making plots from here onwards:
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,1, figsize=(6,8))

axs[0].set_title('Time domain')
axs[0].plot(t,It)
axs[0].axvline(-fwhm*0.5, color='r', alpha=0.5, label='Full-width at half-maximum (FWHM) = %.1f fs'%(fwhm*1e15))
axs[0].axvline( fwhm*0.5, color='r', alpha=0.5)

axs[0].set_xlim(-150e-15, 150e-15)
axs[0].set_ylim(0,1.3)
axs[0].set_xlabel('Time (sec)')

axs[1].set_title('Frequency domain')
axs[1].plot(f,If)

axs[1].axvline(-0.44/fwhm*0.5, color='r', alpha=0.5, label='FWHM should be %.1f THz'%(0.44/fwhm*1e-12) )
axs[1].axvline( 0.44/fwhm*0.5, color='r', alpha=0.5)

axs[1].axvline(-fwhm_fft*0.5, color='g', alpha=0.5, ls='dashed', label='FWHM is actually %.1f THz'%(fwhm_fft*1e-12) )
axs[1].axvline( fwhm_fft*0.5, color='g', alpha=0.5, ls='dashed')

axs[1].set_xlim(-2.0e13,2.0e13)
axs[1].set_ylim(0,30000)
axs[1].set_xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')

for ax in axs:
    ax.legend(fontsize=10)
    ax.set_ylabel('Electric field intensity (arbitrary units)')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('time-bandwidth-product.png', dpi=200)
plt.show()
```

[image]

PS: RP-Photonics is a fantastic resource. It is one of the main textbooks for the field of lasers and photonics.

Comment: Haha, serves me right for being too cocky so far outside my field. Why don't you go ahead and accept your own answer? It sounds plausible enough to me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Paul! It really helped me figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

Edit 2: It seems the devil was in the physics, not the maths, see Dan's self-answer. Squaring the Gaussians indeed moves the locations of the half-maxima by a factor of 1 / sqrt(2) each, so everything is fine. Remains for me to humbly and unreservedly apologise to RP Photonics. End of edit 2.

I'm pretty sure the "bug" you are looking for is with the 0.44, the reference you link doesn't look 100% reliable.

So let's caluclate ourselves what to expect. There are different definitions of Fourier transform out there; [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Definition) seems to be the one numpy is adhering to. The product of the standard deviations of a Gaussian and its Fourier transform in this convention is 1 / (2pi). The half maxima of a zero-mean Gaussian with SD sigma are at +/- sigma sqrt(2 log 2). Thus the product of FWHM's is 1 / (2pi) 8 log 2 = 4 / pi log 2 = 0.8825...

In other words: what you're observing is correct.

Edit: To be fair to RP Photonics, they are not necessarily wrong they may just be using yet another definition of the Fourier transform.